# SQL query to get daily snapshots from state change data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of state change data tied to a bunch of items [Trello Cards and their state changes to be specific].  I'm looking to take that set of transitions [Item_id, From_state, To_state, Timestamp], and generate a set of data that looks like [State, Day, Item Count] for each state.

Currently, I'm building this list in a fairly CPU intensive way from Python after returning all of the Transitions, and aggregating them.  I was looking for a faster way to do this in PSQL.

Answer (score 1):

With  [Item_id, From_state, To_state, Timestamp] you need a lot of work to calculate a snapshot, but if you had data like this it would be very straightforward: [Item_id, state, start_timestamp, end_timestamp]

Luckily, it's possible to transition from one format to the other:

For this kind of problem, I find the easiest approach is to:

- Generate a list of days
- Generate list of states of interest (you need this list because there may be days with zero cards in a state for a particular date,
  and you presumably want a row saying zero rather than no row)
- Transform data into [Item_id, state, start_timestamp, end_timestamp] format
- For each day, calculate how many items are in each state

With that in mind, something following the below pattern should work.

```
--CTE for step 1
with days as (SELECT day::date as d
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07'
                     , timestamp '2004-08-16'
                     , interval  '1 day') day)
--CTE FOR step 2                     
, state_list as (select from_state as s from transition_table t group by from_state)
--CTE for step 3
, time_in_state as( select t.item_id, t.to_state as item_state, t."Timestamp" as start_timestamp
   , (select min(t2."Timestamp") from transition_table t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id and t2."Timestamp" > t."Timestamp" ) as end_timestamp
  from transition_table t )

--finally, the actual query is straightforward
select days.d
 , state_list.s as item_state
 , count(distinct t.item_id) as items_in_state_at_some_point_in_day
from days
 join state_list on TRUE --full join
 left join time_in_state t on t.item_state = state_list.s and days.d >= date_trunc('day', t.start_timestamp) and days.d < coalesce(t.end_timestamp, now() )

 group by days.d, state_list.s
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an Postgres query that aggregates the data by day and state ?

Depending on your computation method for the states, this should be something like :

```
SELECT 
    t.from_state,
    t.timestamp::date as day,
    COUNT(*) as item_count
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY 
    t.from_state, 
    t.timestamp::date
```